# not getting integer value from SharedPreference

Tags: android, get, int, sharedpreferences

I am trying to store user id in SharedPreference in one activity and want to get this integer id in any activity.
To put this value in Shared Preference i use following code.

```
SharedPreferences myPrefs = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = myPrefs.edit();
prefsEditor.putInt("userId", varaible);                 
prefsEditor.commit();
```

Then i am trying to get this value, i use following code for this

```
SharedPreferences myPrefs = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    int userId = myPrefs.getInt("userId", -1);
```

But it return me -1 not userId. and if i use following line to fetch integer value then it will showing runtime exception.

```
    int userId = myPrefs.getInt("userId", Integer(null));
```

I don't understand what's wrong in my code. How to get this integer userId in my another activity.
Please give me any reference or hint.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the value of `varaible`?

Comment: variable=4; it userid which return json object

Comment: try using getDefaultSharedPreferences instead of getSharedPreferences.

Comment: Your code looks fine... Are you sure that you are actually executing the "save" code? Are these Activities in the same Application?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change this:

```
SharedPreferences myPrefs = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
int userId = myPrefs.getInt("userId", -1);
```

to this

```
SharedPreferences myPrefs = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
int userId = myPrefs.getInt("userId", 0);
```

it should work that way.

Comment: But this simply changes the default value, not why the defautl value is being returned...

Comment: Maybe yes, but I have got that problem before and changing the -1 to 0 worked for me, that's why I posted it.

Comment: @RotaryHeart: i don't know how it's possible but your trick solve my problem. -1 to 0 only change default value but here your solution give me correct answer.. Thanks a lots.

Comment: @Sandip Armal Patil: Glad to hear, happy codding :)

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code and I tested this exact case and it is working perfectly. For sure you can use the default value as **-1**.

Do you have both activities in the same application?

What I can suggest for debugging is to make sure that your application runs in the sequence you expect and that the value is stored correctly. You can try to retrieve it directly after storing it within the same activity.