# Taking user selection in a spinner, storing it in sharedPreferences, and using it in another activity

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, android-spinner

I need the user to choose a restaurant, got a pretty large list with different selections.
I then need to save that choice, preferably in something like sharedPreferences. And use it in another activity to display some data from an excel document.

currently my code looks like this:

in onCreate:

```
resturantSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.resturantSpinner);
     // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.resturant_arrays, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
   // Apply the adapter to the spinner
    resturantSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

onItemSelected:

```
public void onItemSelected(View view) {
      int userChoice = resturantSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
      SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("resturantFile",0);
      SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = sharedPref.edit();
      prefEditor.putInt("userChoiceSpinner", userChoice);
      prefEditor.commit();
}
```

And retrieving the data, in another activity:

```
resturantTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resturantChoice);

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("resturantFile",MODE_PRIVATE);
    int resturantChoice = sharedPref.getInt("userChoiceSpinner",-1);

    resturantTextView.setText("" + resturantChoice);
```

I just use the textView to see what it saves like, and currently it just shows -1

edit: might as well just add this, userChoice value is 0.

Comment: Can you debug and see what value userChoice has?

Comment: userCoice value is 0..

Comment: Do you call sharedPref.edit() anywhere else in the first activity before you go to the second? Calling .edit() resets sharedPref editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Add like this   `SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("resturantFile",Activity.MODE_PRIVATE)` instead of
`SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("resturantFile",0)`.

For example: The way to save

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("your_prefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
editor.putInt("your_int_key", yourIntValue);
editor.commit();
```

The way to retrieve data in another activity:

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("your_prefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
int myIntValue = sp.getInt("your_int_key", -1);
```

If that is not working for you then try this one: 
Change the default value -1 to 0,

```
int myIntValue = sp.getInt("your_int_key", 0);
```

For more information use this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14153286/not-getting-integer-value-from-sharedpreference).

Comment: Did you check userChoice variable to make sure it is not empty before you save  in  SharedPreferences?

Comment: Happy to hear you solved it. If this answer helped to solve it for you, could you please mark it as accepted answer.