# how to store spinner selected value and retrieve it in another activity for display

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-spinner

i've searched for a solution on google ,and on stack overflow.Yes i also know this could be a duplicate of another question asked in stack overflow but i tried the code snippets offered but none of them worked.Like: [Taking user selection in a spinner, storing it in sharedPrefences, and using it in another activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24131348/taking-user-selection-in-a-spinner-storing-it-in-sharedprefences-and-using-it) and [not getting integer value from SharedPreference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14153286/not-getting-integer-value-from-sharedpreference) and http://www.acnenomor.com/4379973p1/how-to-save-spinner-selecteditem-to-sharedpreferences

Here is my problem.I have the first activity,with two spinners from this tutorial http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-spinner-drop-down-list-example/ .On pressing the submit button,id like to save the selected values on SharesPreferences.On going to the second activity,i retrieve the selected values and display them on a text view.So that on the next app launch i go to the second activity to find the displayed saved values.I've been really stranded on this.Please point me in the right direction.Any help will be very much appreciated.

main activity

```js
public class MyAndroidAppActivity extends Activity {
 
  private Spinner spinner1, spinner2;
  private Button btnSubmit;
 
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.main);
 
 addItemsOnSpinner2();
 addListenerOnButton();
 addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection();
  }
 
  // add items into spinner dynamically
  public void addItemsOnSpinner2() {
 
 spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
 List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
 list.add("list 1");
 list.add("list 2");
 list.add("list 3");
 ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
  android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
 dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
 spinner2.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
  }
 
  public void addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection() {
 spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
 spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomOnItemSelectedListener());
  }
 
  // get the selected dropdown list value
  public void addListenerOnButton() {
 
 spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
 spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
 btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);
 
 btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
 
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
 
     Toast.makeText(MyAndroidAppActivity.this,
  "OnClickListener : " + 
                "\nSpinner 1 : "+ String.valueOf(spinner1.getSelectedItem()) + 
                "\nSpinner 2 : "+ String.valueOf(spinner2.getSelectedItem()),
   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
 
 });
  }
}
```

CustomOnItemSelectedListener.java

```js
public class CustomOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {
 
  public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,long id) {
 Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), 
  "OnItemSelectedListener : " + parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(),
  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
 
  @Override
  public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  }
 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to do it. I used this tutorial (http://androidopentutorials.com/android-sharedpreferences-tutorial-and-example/)
I modified this code to fit what I wanted

```
public void onClick(View v) {
text = String.valueOf(spinner1.getSelectedItem()) + String.valueOf(spinner2.getSelectedItem());
                    sharedPreference.save(context, text);
```